# Accessing WiFi access points Logs

Tags: networking, python

i need to make a project for a client, he asked to develop a system with raspberry pi 3 to monitor search history at home routers and some other things. so my question is, do the wifi router at home store web history? if so how can someone access it using raspberry pi 3.

i'm using rasbian on raspberry pi 3, and python to code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, no.

But it depends of the software running on the wifi router.

If it runs *openwrt* and the likes, you can probably logs anything like DNS requests, or whatever you like, given the router is powerfull enough.

Otherwise, it would be best to replace the wifi router with one of yours running a linux box.

Comment: if i convert raspberry pi in to the access point would it make it easy to access the logs?

Comment: It depends on what you want to log. You have total control over the internals of the pi. But you can't get anything. *https* is encrypted so you can know the IP, in some case the site accessed, not the page. Search history in google will not dot it for example.

Comment: i want to log the web browsers search history, would that be possible?